# How to get leading and trailing spaces in String java

Tags: java, string

In all other related posts people asked about removing leading or/and trailing spaces in String java. Now, my question is how to get the leading or trailing spaces? What I could think is for example to get the trailing spaces using such a function:

```
private String getTrailingSpaces(String str) {
     return str.replace(str.replaceFirst("\\s+$", ""), "");
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is correct or even if it is, is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert but I think you should perform 2 distinct regexp, one for leading spaces and one for trailing spaces.

```
private static final Pattern LEADING = Pattern.compile("^\\s+");
private static final Pattern TRAILING = Pattern.compile("\\s+$");

public String getLeadingSpaces(String str) {
    Matcher m = LEADING.matcher(str);
    if(m.find()){
        return m.group(0);
    }
    return "";  
}

public String getTrailingSpaces(String str) {
    Matcher m = TRAILING.matcher(str);
    if(m.find()){
        return m.group(0);
    }
    return "";  
}
```

Comment: You can combine those into a single pattern and get the individual groups from the matcher.

Comment: I tried, but I wasn't able to find the right "joining" regexp

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    String leading = str.replaceAll("^(\\s+).+", "$1");
    String tailing = str.replaceAll(".+?(\\s+)$", "$1");
```

Comment: I don't understand what does the second argument mean!

Comment: Second argument means content of group #1. Group number one is (\\s++). All thing means replace all input with content in group #1

Comment: What if your string just contains spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
private String getTrailingSpaces(String str) {
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*(\\s+)$");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
  String trailing = "";
  if (m.matches) {
    trailing = m.group(1);
  }
  return trailing;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.You would need [ArrayUtils from Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) though.

```
String str1 = " abc  ";
char[] cs = str1.toCharArray();
Character[] characters = ArrayUtils.toObject(cs);
// System.out.println(characters.length); // 6
for (Character character : characters) {
  if (character.isSpace(character.charValue())) {
    // PROCESS ACCORDINGLY
  } else {
    // PROCESS ACCORDINGLY
  }
}
```